# human gene PCR primers database

Tags: pcr

I wonder if there is a place on the internet to get PCR primers for a specific gene. 
For instance, exon 15 in CFTR gene. I don't want to design myself because I am sure sombody else already did it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is, obviously, yes.

```
Primerbank
```

[Here.](https://pga.mgh.harvard.edu/primerbank/) You can search primers using accession number or Gene-ID

Comment: Note that those are primers for real-time PCR, not regular PCR.

Answer (score 0):

You need primers for one exon only?  Why can't you get the sequence and flanking sequence, and put that in to primer3?

http://bioinfo.ut.ee/primer3-0.4.0/